# The complex equation: $z^4 + 1 = \dfrac{1 - iz^3}{1 - z^4}$ How to solve it in $\mathbb{C}$ numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have here an complex equation in $\mathbb{C}$ numbers: $$z^4 + 1 = \dfrac{1 - iz^3}{1 - z^4}.$$

My question is how to solve this complex equation? What is the best way to solve it?

*My attempt:* Multiply both sides by $1-z^4$ to get $$(z^4+1)(1-z^4)=1-iz^3$$ so $1-z^8=1-iz^3$ gives $z^8=z^3i$. How to continue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: cross multiply by the denominator.

Comment: $(z^4+1)(1-z^4)=-(z^4-1)(z^4+1)=-(z^8-1)=1-z^8$

Comment: Yes, I came through my step to here. I got the equation $$z^8 = z^3i$$ and then I stopped, cause I don't know how to get a solutions from here. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please show your efforts by editing your attempt into the post.

Comment: @Andrej Guess you are supposed to know how to solve equations like $z^n = i$. If not, what is the context in which you found this problem?

Comment: One answer is $z=0$.  If $z \ne 0$, then divide both sides by $z^3$.

Comment: Ok, my attempt. $$z^4 + 1 = \dfrac{1 - iz^3}{1 - z^4}$$. First multiply equation by $1 - z^4$. $$(z^4 + 1)(1 - z^4) = 1 - iz^3$$. Then I get the equation $z^8 = z^3i$ and then I stop.

Comment: $z=0$ solves the equation. So assume $z\not=0$ and obtain $z^5=i$. You should be able to solve the equation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I think will now solve the equation.

Comment: I think the result would be more recognisable if you make the substitution $z=iw$, so that $z^8=z^3i$ becomes $w^8=w^3$.

Comment: Ok, either way. For equation $w^8 = w^3$ and rearrange the equation on $w^3(w^5 - 1) = 0$. I got the solutions: $w_{1,2,3} = 0$, $w_4 = \cos(0) + i \sin(0) = 1$, $w_5 = \cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{5}) +i \sin(\dfrac{2\pi}{5})$, $w_6 = \cos(\dfrac{4\pi}{5}) + i \sin(\dfrac{4\pi}{5})$, $w_7 = \cos(\dfrac{6\pi}{5}) + i \sin(\dfrac{6\pi}{5})$ and $w_8 = \cos(\dfrac{8\pi}{5}) + i \sin(\dfrac{8\pi}{5})$.

Comment: For equation $z^5 = i$ I got the solutions: $z_0 = \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{10}) + i \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{10})$, $z_1 = \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2}) + i \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}) = i$, $z_2 = \cos(\dfrac{9\pi}{10}) + i \sin(\dfrac{9\pi}{10})$, $z_3 = \cos(\dfrac{13\pi}{10}) + i \sin(\dfrac{13\pi}{10})$ and $z_4 = \cos(\dfrac{17\pi}{10}) + i \sin(\dfrac{17\pi}{10})$.

Comment: Is this right solution? Anyone?

Comment: @Andrej looks correct to me.